# How can you incorporate the hydrophone calibration in Avisoft?

Tags: calibration, soundtrap, software

I am stuck in being able to calibrate the avisoft. I have a soundtrap Hf300 and I'm not sure how to insert the data into the avisoft calibration. Any advice? Thanks
All the best

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, input the end-to-end calibration value for whichever mode you recorded your files in. Assuming you did your recordings in 'high gain' mode, then you'd put **-176.4** as our "**reference SPL**" in Avisoft.

Then, check out page 19 of the [soundtrap user guide](http://www.oceaninstruments.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ST-User-Guide.pdf). While it does not specify how Avisoft reads in data (and I am unfamiliar with Avisoft), it tells you how to import it into PAMGuard, Matlab, PAMGuide and Audacity, which could be helpful.

I would guess that you'd put **1 Vp** as the drop-down selection for "**full-scale range**"... any Avisoft-experienced folks out there?

Comment: Super thank you!! thats help a lot!